# Highlighting and syntax trouble in vim using rmarkdown

Tags: vim, syntax, r-markdown, highlight, pandoc

I would like to get Vim to stop highlighting list characters (`-`,`*`) and heading characters (`#`) in rmarkdown. You can find a screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAiyX.jpg.

This is happening when I set the file type to either pandoc or rmd. This is also happening no matter what terminal or colortheme I use.

I have the plugins: `vim-pandoc`, `vim-pandoc-syntax`, and `vim-rmarkdown` installed.

I would like to know a way to make the two characters just appear normally.

I would also like to know if there is a way to make italicized text in tables and headings appear italicized. As far as modifying the appearance of italicized text, I've tried using: `hi Italic ctermfg=red cterm=italic` in my vimrc, but that does not seem to affect the text in between asterisks (`*`) in rmd files. I admit I don't know much about the way that syntax works in Vim. Do I need to modify `after/ftplugin/rmd.vim` or `runtime/syntax/rmd.vim`? What is the difference between the two?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there any benefit not using rmarkdown with Rstudio?

Comment: Yes. I would love to be able to use the text editor I use for everything else. I am able to customize it extensively to my particular liking with key-bindings, color schemes, plugins, and syntax. Although in this case, the customizability of syntax is what I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax highlighter does not seem to recognize the bullet points, but thinks that they mark the beginning of an italic span. Maybe you have a clash of plugins. You could also try another highlighter (e.g. `vim-polyglot`, supports italics).

`vim-pandoc-syntax` uses the *conceal* feature (`:h conceal`). You can recolor the highlighting group `Conceal` to change the appearance of the replacement characters.

You can put changes to existing syntax files in `.vim/after/syntax/rmd.vim`. Files in `syntax` are executed when they are needed for the first time, but at most once per session. Files in `ftplugin` are executed every time the file type is changed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I put `hi Conceal ctermbg=bg` in my `.vimrc` and it worked!